# Interface method return type conditional on other member

Tags: typescript

Assuming that the value of a member (`single`) is statically known (i.e. a literal `boolean` in this case), is it possible to pick the return type of another member method based on that?

```
interface I {
    single: boolean;
    // Want the return type to be 'number'
    // if single === true and 'Set<number>' otherwise.
    returnSingle: () => number | Set<number>
}
```

Edit: would this be correct?

```
type SingleOrSet<C extends boolean> = C extends true ? number : Set<number>;

interface I<T extends boolean> {
    single: T;
    // Want the return type to be 'number'
    // if single === true and 'Set<number>' otherwise.
    returnSingle: () => SingleOrSet<T>
}

const p: I<true> = {single: true, returnSingle: () => {return 1}};
```

Is there a way for `T` to be inferred in usage so it doesn't have to be passed as a type argument to `I`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a union type using an object type with `single: true` and another with `single: false`:

```typescript
type I =
    |   {
        single: true;
        returnSingle: () => number;
    }
    |   {
        single: false;
        returnSingle: () => Set<number>;
    };
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAklC8AoKKoB9UG9mtwZwEsA7AcwBsIAuKYAJwFcIBuHXFWiYe2ogZWPJUoACgCUCAHxQi9ALYAjCLRa4Avq3RYN+ARWoAzAIZk8zbag5ce-UnpHj4U3pwA8MhUokrUqlogD0-lAA6gD2tADWeIgAxqFEeMBQBACM1HDwUNg6tkJ0jAA0GpbcfLpCYpJQACwATEW+iAFBYZHRcQlJBLXpCFkahLkGxqZFuCXW5dSVjtIQAO5QzsDCANp1ALqiDX6BUACitLThUIZ4UAAmEIQcF7HxickAzL2Z2aiDgsMmEGMWnKUbF97FU6jsmntDsdaKdzlcbhA7h1HgRqq9+jlgflfsUAZMhiDZkQFktOGtNttEI0gA)

Or you could provide aliases for the union members, which might be clearer:

```typescript
interface ISingle {
    single: true;
    returnSingle: () => number;
}
interface IMultiple {
    single: false;
    returnSingle: () => Set<number>;
}
type I = ISingle | IMultiple;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGVQHMA2KDeAUMicgM7Z4BcyYUArhANzGlQRj1QiYi4Q0AFAEpkAXgB8yEPQC2AI2gsAvoVCRYiFKgCy9HGGAAHPMiKlylAcng4yzViXaduvfkNGTk6DgB4ZCtASKoRgAJ5G2uJobqYAPmh6BsZ4LIQA9OnIAOoA9lAA1mSECLkgZGDIwACMNKjR5qQUfNS0DBAANI7Izlw8Vh7iUgAsAExdymmZOflFJWUVVaN1Dd3N7jZwdp3dva4DyCJD0hAA7t4cggDaYwC6whNTWQCiUFD5yHBkyAAmEBTsH7zcqVYAAZhWYjMawOtnsXQse36LWsRy8Y0ehAyLzeHy+v3+wEBwMWwGGkOhFnWrTojARbA4fViqM8UhAZwuYGudwehEmhCAA)

With either of those, these work:

```typescript
const i1: I = {
    single: true,
    returnSingle: () => 42,
};

const i2: I = {
    single: false,
    returnSingle: () => new Set([42]),
};
```

...but these raise errors as desired:

```typescript
const i3: I = {
    single: false,
    returnSingle: () => 42,
};

const i4: I = {
    single: true,
    returnSingle: () => new Set([42]),
};
```